# Custom Buttons on dynamic GUI

Tags: swing, jbutton, custom-component

My Swing-Application sets the size of the JFrame via `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()`, and all Elements are relative to this values, so basically the application adapts to the screen resolution.

Now I have a problem with my custom buttons. For now, I create three different ImageIcons (normal, rollover and pressed) and add them to the button. But naturally, if I run the application with a different resolution than 1920x1080 (which is my default), the buttons are too big.

I found this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234726/auto-resizing-jbutton-icon) and tried the solution by creating an Icon, put it on a Jlabel and add the label to the button, but nothing is displaid. Also, I do not need to resize the window.

What is the fastest and solution for this topic? An option would be to create all custom images individually for every resolution, add the x-value of the resolution at the end of the image name and make let's say a switch case to check which image should be load, but I think this is a very expensive and time-consuming solution. Is there an efficient way to automatically size a loaded image to a certian size relative to the screen resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an [`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Image.html), you can invoke [`getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) to retrieve a resized image.

If you have an [`ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/ImageIcon.html),you can invoke `getImage()` on it, to retrieve an `Image` and then use the solution suggested above.

`getScaledInstance` returns an `Image` which you can wrap back into an `ImageIcon` and set on a `JButton` or a `JLabel`.

So, I would create my images with the highest resolution possible and then downscale them to the appropriate resolution.

Here is a small snippet (inspired from @mKorbel solution you started from):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ResizeIconInButton extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "http://duke.kenai.com/misc/Bullfight.jpg";
    private JButton myButton = new JButton();

    public ResizeIconInButton() throws MalformedURLException {
        myButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(new URL(IMAGE_PATH)).getImage().getScaledInstance(600, 400, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        add(myButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setTitle("Resize Icon In Button");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ResizeIconInButton main = new ResizeIconInButton();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Small note: it is not recommended to extend JFrame but I tried to stay as close as possible to the original code.